# Multivariate LSTM not training correctly

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm trying to predict pollution level at time t using the 10 previous pm values and alot of other information. I have 168 features in total.

```
Train X: (7126, 10, 168), Train y: (7126, 1)
Val X: (2029, 10, 168), Val y: (2029, 1)
Test X: (1009, 10, 168), Test y: (1009, 1)
Timesteps: 10, Features 168, outputs 1
```

According to the keras website, LSTMs take in inputs of shape (num_rows, timesteps, num_features), which is how ive structured the above.

I have the following Model params:

```
epochs = 150
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
# fit network
history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_data=(val_x, val_y),epochs=epochs, callbacks = [es])
```

However, it doesnt seem to train at all. The loss does not decrease across timesteps.

[image]

Anyone has any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Any reason for using `activation='relu'` for LSTM layer? Didn't the default activation, i.e. `tanh`, work? Further, have you normalized the feature values?

Comment: @today would that make much of a difference? And yes all features are normalized except for the boolean features